# Delete all layers in Photoshop except the active one

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is it possible to delete all the layers in Photoshop except the one layer you are on/the one layer that is active?

I don't want to hide all the other layers, I actually want to delete them.

Comment: ctrl-click [windows] or Cmd-click [mac] all the layers you want to delete, or shift-click the lot then deselect your keeper] then hit the Trash can at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple trick which does what you want:

1. Open the Layers window. (Window Menu > Layers)
2. In the Layers window, right click (control key + click on a Mac) on the hide/show (eye) button to the left of the layer you want to keep.
3. Click "Show/Hide all other layers" in the contextual menu that appears. The layer you want to keep should now be the only visible layer.
4. In the upper right hand corner of the Layers window, open the tab menu and click "Delete Hidden Layers". All layers that were hidden should now be deleted, leaving your visible layer behind.

I tried this on Adobe Photoshop CS4, however there may be different methods for different versions.